# How to get the owner and group of a folder with Python on a Linux machine?

Tags: python, linux, directory, owner

How can I get the owner and group IDs of a directory using Python under Linux?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Use [`os.stat()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.stat) to get the uid and gid of the file. Then, use [`pwd.getpwuid()`](http://docs.python.org/library/pwd.html#pwd.getpwuid) and [`grp.getgrgid()`](http://docs.python.org/library/grp.html#grp.getgrgid) to get the user and group names respectively.

```
import grp
import pwd
import os

stat_info = os.stat('/path')
uid = stat_info.st_uid
gid = stat_info.st_gid
print uid, gid

user = pwd.getpwuid(uid)[0]
group = grp.getgrgid(gid)[0]
print user, group
```

Answer (score 13):

Since Python 3.4.4, the `Path` class of [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.owner) module provides a nice syntax for this:

```
from pathlib import Path
whatever = Path("relative/or/absolute/path/to_whatever")
if whatever.exists():
    print("Owner: %s" % whatever.owner())
    print("Group: %s" % whatever.group())
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [os.stat](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/os.html#os.stat):

```
>>> s = os.stat('.')
>>> s.st_uid
1000
>>> s.st_gid
1000
```

`st_uid` is the user id of the owner, `st_gid` is the group id. See the linked documentation for other information that can be acuired through `stat`.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use [os.stat](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#files-and-directories):

> Perform a stat system call on the given path. The return value is an object whose attributes correspond to the members of the stat structure, namely: st_mode (protection bits), `st_ino` (inode number), `st_dev` (device), `st_nlink` (number of hard links), **`st_uid` (user id of owner), `st_gid` (group id of owner)**, `st_size` (size of file, in bytes), `st_atime` (time of most recent access), `st_mtime` (time of most recent content modification), `st_ctime` (platform dependent; time of most recent metadata change on Unix, or the time of creation on Windows)

There's an example at the link to `os.stat` above.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `os.stat` function.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux, it is much easier.
Install tree with the command yum install tree. Then execute the command 'tree -a -u -g'

Comment: It's not in Python.

Comment: And even outside of Python, why not just use `ls -al`, and look for the file? Or `ls -al | grep FILENAME` to get only that row.