# Python - list files that belong to specific 'group'

Tags: python

In python I can easily list files in a directory with `os.listdir('dir')` but how could I easily filter those files to those which belong to a specific group?  This is simply done in unix with `find . -group "foo"`

For example, let's say I have the following three files:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 foo foo 0 Sep 15 08:57 foo.txt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 bar bar 0 Sep 15 08:34 bar.txt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 foo foo 0 Sep 15 08:57 faz.txt
```

How can I get only those files which belong to the 'group' `foo` using python?

The files returned should be `foo.txt` and `faz.txt` ideally in a `list` object.

This [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927866/how-to-get-the-owner-and-group-of-a-folder-with-python-on-a-linux-machine) addresses how to get the group/user after you know the file.  I want to filter the list to only a specific group.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the owner and group of a folder with Python on a Linux machine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927866/how-to-get-the-owner-and-group-of-a-folder-with-python-on-a-linux-machine)

Comment: can't you just split it by \n then by space and filter by value on 2nd position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this may work:

```
import os
import grp
gid = grp.getgrnam('foo').gr_gid

file_list = []
for fle in os.listdir('dir'):
    if os.stat(fle).st_gid == gid:
        file_list.append(fle)
```

or as a one-liner (list-comprehension):

```
file_list = [fle for fle in os.listdir('dir') if os.stat(fle).st_gid == gid]
```

Comment: This nearly got me there, but I needed to change the last `gid` to `gid.gr_gid` for it to match.

Answer (score 0):

The [`grp` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/grp.html) comes to your help, together with [Python's list comprehensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension#Python) that are very handy for succintctly filtering arrays.

```
[f for f in os.listdir("dir") if grp.getgrgid(os.stat(f).st_gid).gr_name == "foo"]
```

If you are content with just the group id, you can avoid `grp` altogether:

```
[f for f in os.listdir("dir") if os.stat(f).st_gid == 1234]
```

(Replace, of course, `1234` with the actual group id)